Databricks Notebooks deployment to Private-Link enabled Azure Databricks workspace using Azure Devops Pipelines do not work
We have Private Link enabled Databricks Workspace, created using Vnet Injection.
We are trying to deploy Notebooks from Azure repos using Azure Devops Pipeline,
Following is the yaml written:
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
  


stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs: 
    - job: copy
      steps:
      
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'Notebooks'
          publishLocation: 'Container'


  - stage: Development
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployTodev
        displayName: Deploy to Dev
        environment: 'DBX_Test'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
           deploy:
            steps:
            
            - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                downloadType: 'single'
                artifactName: 'Notebooks'
                downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            
            - task: CmdLine@2
              inputs:
                script: |
                  echo Write your commands here
                  
                  echo Hello world
                  
                  
                  cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
                  
                  
                  dir /p

            - task: configuredatabricks@0
              inputs:
                url: $(databricksHost)
                token: $(databricksToken)


            - task: databricksDeployScripts@0
              inputs:
                authMethod: 'bearer'
                bearerToken: $(databricksToken)
                region: $(region)
                localPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Notebooks/'
                databricksPath: '/deploy'
                clean: true

This is executing successfully, but not copying the notebooks to deploy folder.
What could be the issue here?
could it be because we are using "windows-latest" as agent VM, and it doesnt have connectivity.

As per the yaml, you are deploying from DBX_Test environment not agent. I tried the yaml with Databricks which doesn't have network restriction, it works. The notebook is deployed to Workspace\deploy. Please check the Databricks task log, is it successful to connect to Databricks? If not, please check the network on your environment DBX_Test? How do you configure it? Does it have same Vnet so that it can connect to Databricks? If connection is OK, please show your databricksDeployScripts@0 log, is the file skipped? Do you have the notebook, eg: notebook.py in the repo?

@wadezhou-MSFT, The environment is only meant for Approvals & checks, No resources attached to it.
deployment works with Public enabled workspace but we have enabled Private end points on WS.
No errors encountered in the pipeline. Pipeline is completing successfully but files are not getting imported.

If you don't configure the environment with resource, the pipeline will automatically apply a hosted machine. As it only failed with private endpoint workspace, I'm afraid you need to use an self hosted agent which has same private endpoint for deploying. In addition, when you say the task is successful, did you add variables system.debug as true in pipeline to get the detail deployment log? It will show the deployment details at the log end. https://i.sstatic.net/dYuu4.png
